# setting selected values in dropdown not proper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code for setting the selected value in the drop down, i am splitting the values from a comma separated string, it's not working as expected.

if use  `string='text1,text2,text3,text4'` , it's working, if i use `string='text2'` its not working.

```
  var string='text1,text2,text3,text4';
  var opts = string.split(",");
  function selectOptions() 
  {
    var obj = $('#dropdown');
    for (var i in opts) 
    {
    obj.find('option[value=' + i + ']').prop('selected', true);
    }
  }
  selectOptions();
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEwyd/4/).

Comment: Your code is WRONG, change your string to `var string='text2,text4,text5';` and see the output : http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/xEwyd/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there's no match between your select values and the opts indexes generated by your split().

It's a conception problem

If you really want to base your comparison on label instead of option value, you can do it this way:

```
var string='text2,text4';
var opts = string.split(",");
function selectOptions() {
    var $obj = $('#dropdown option');

    for (var i in opts) {
        $obj.each(function(){
           $option = $(this);
           if($option.text() === opts[i]) $option.prop('selected', true);
        });
    }
}
selectOptions();
```

See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xEwyd/11/)

Comment: how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by:

```
var string='text2';
var opts = string.split(",");
function selectOptions() {
    var obj = $('#dropdown');
    for (var i in opts) {
        console.log(i);
        obj.find('option:contains(' + opts[i] + ')').prop('selected', true);
    }
}
selectOptions();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEwyd/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
<select id="dropdown" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="text1">text1</option>
    <option value="text2">text2</option>
    <option value="text3">text3</option>
    <option value="text4">text4</option>
    <option value="text5">text5</option>
    <option value="text6">text6</option>
    <option value="text7">text7</option>
</select>
```

Code:

```
var string='text4';
var opts = string.split(",");
function selectOptions() {
    var obj = $('#dropdown');
    for (var item in opts) {
        obj.find('option[value=' + opts[item] + ']').prop('selected', true);
    }
}
selectOptions();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/xEwyd/13/)

Answer (score 0):

In your `for(var i in opts)` `i` contains the index of the current item, so it always starts at `0`. You could change your html and JavaScript a bit like so: http://jsfiddle.net/xEwyd/7/

I added actual values to the html. If that's not possible, you could always change the `string` to contain indexes instead of values.